# issue with Domain, DNS and Hosting

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

I bought domains from GoDaddy.
I bought hosting from NFS.
I changed my DNS from GD to NFS.

Do I require to host DNS on NFS for website to work properly, or can I host DNS back on GD?

I am paying for DNS to GoDaddy already. And now NFS is charging me too.

Answer (score 1):

Just setup the domain to point to the NFS hosting, follow these easy steps:

1. Login to GoDaddy
2. Click my account
3. Click Domains
4. Find domain and click launch on it.
5. Ensure that you are using the name servers of GoDaddy's and not NFS hosting as there's no need to switch.
6. Look at DNS Manager and click launch (See Screenshot).
   [Godaddy DNS Manager http://www.bybe.net/downloads/godaddy-dns-manager](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/godaddy-dns-manager)
7. Once in the DNS manager add the A record with your server IP
8. Add @ to the mail record
9. Add mail.yourdomain.com to the MX records with Priority 0 (See Screenshot for the last 3 steps.
   [Godaddy DNS Setup http://www.bybe.net/downloads/godaddy-dns-setup](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/godaddy-dns-setup)
10. Now you just need to tell your webhost of your domain, I'm assuming you provided this when you signed up for the hosting, if not your need to add the domain under addon domain in cpanel or plesk. You can always contact your web host and tell them that you've updated the A records pointed to their server, and they should be able to do the rest.
11. Wait 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

For easier, please just ask your registrar (GoDaddy) to point your domain to NFS name server, you just need to wait 12-24 hours, the DNS will be resolved. Simple and less headache. :)

Answer (score 0):

My Domain Registrar GoDaddy offers DNS hosting. My web hosting provider NFS offers DNS hosting.

Web hosting provider provides a bunch of IP address. This IP address is where my site physically is.

But, I still need to convert my domain name, say: www.example.com, to IP address that my hosting provider provided.

For that all I need is my domain to point to the web-hosting IP address.

I do not need to host DNS with my web hosting provider.

In the end, I am hosting DNS with GoDaddy, Web site with NearlyFreeSpeech and Domain registrar is GoDaddy; and thus I don't have to pay NFS.

Let's see this answer in other terms.

Hosting provider: NFS. IP address = x.y.z.a
Domain  provider: GD.  Points to = some GD specific IP = g.g.g.g
DNS host by NFS : NFS.NFS.NFS.com
DNS host by GD  : GD.GD.GD.com

problem: Do I need to change my DNS along with point to value to run my site successfully?

Solution: no.

Hosting provider: NFS. IP address = x.y.z.a
Domain  provider: GD.  Points to  = x.y.z.a
DNS host by GD  : GD.GD.GD.com

I tried it and it worked. I have tried my best to explain. Thanks.